# A perplexing phenomenon in SwiftUI:

Tags: swiftui, overlay

As shown in the code below, my `CardContentView` consists of elements arranged vertically in a `VStack`. However, when I place it within an overlay, it behaves as if it were in a `ZStack`. Why is this so?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hywuO.png)

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestView: View {
    @Namespace var namespace
    @State var isShowDetail = false
    @State var selectedCardIndex: Int?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(.gray.opacity(0.05))
                .ignoresSafeArea()
        }
        .overlay {
            if let selectedCardIndex, isShowDetail {
                DetailView(selectedCardIndex)
                    .transition(.asymmetric(insertion: .identity, removal: .offset(y: 5)))
            }
        }
        .overlay {
            CardContentView()
        }
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    func TesttView(_ index: Int) -> some View {
        Rectangle()
            .frame(width: .infinity, height: 100)
            .foregroundColor(.red.opacity(0.3))
            .overlay {
                Text("\(index)")
            }
    }

    @ViewBuilder
    func DetailView(_ index: Int) -> some View {
        VStack {
            TesttView(index)
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: index, in: namespace)
        }
    }

    @ViewBuilder
    func CardContentView() -> some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                    ForEach(0..<10) { index in
                        VStack {
                            if index == selectedCardIndex && isShowDetail {
                                Rectangle()
                                    .fill(.clear)
                            } else {
                                TesttView(index)
                                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: index, in: namespace)
                                    .offset(y: isShowDetail ? 1000 : 0)
                                    .rotation3DEffect(
                                        .init(degrees: 10),
                                        axis: (x: 1.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0),
                                        anchor: .center,
                                        anchorZ: 0.0,
                                        perspective: 1.0
                                    )
                                    .onTapGesture {
                                        selectedCardIndex = index

                                        withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 5)) {
                                            isShowDetail.toggle()
                                        }
                                    }
                                    .padding()
                                    

                            }
                        }
                }
            }
        }
        .overlay {
            if let selectedCardIndex, isShowDetail {
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
                            .onTapGesture {
                                withAnimation {
                                    isShowDetail.toggle()
                                }
                            }

                        Spacer()

                        Text("Detail")
                            .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .bold))
                    }
                    DetailView(selectedCardIndex)
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }        
    }
}

struct TestView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestView()
    }
}
```

When I remove CardContentView from the overlay and place it in a VStack, it returns to normal.

```
var body: some View {
        VStack {
            CardContentView()
        }
        .overlay {
            if let selectedCardIndex, isShowDetail {
                DetailView(selectedCardIndex)
                    .transition(.asymmetric(insertion: .identity, removal: .offset(y: 5)))
            }
        }
        .overlay {
//            CardContentView()
        }
    }
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5Ro5.png)

Comment: Why are you putting it in an `overlay` in the first place?

Comment: It's best to make a `View` and use `body` instead of your own custom `@ViewBuilder` func

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `CardContentView` behaves as if it were in a `ZStack` when placed within an overlay because of how SwiftUI handles the layout and layering of views.

When you use the overlay modifier, it overlays the content on top of the base view. However, in your case, you are overlaying multiple views on top of each other within the `VStack`. SwiftUI uses a `ZStack` internally to handle this overlaying of views. This is why you observe behavior similar to a `ZStack`.

When you remove the `CardContentView` from the overlay and place it in a VStack, the views are arranged one after another as expected because `VStack` stacks views vertically.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the order of VStack and ForEach is incorrect.

Instead of:

```
ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
        ForEach(0..<10) { index in
            VStack {
```

this works:

```
ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
    VStack {
        ForEach(0..<10) { index in
```